# Line get duplicated instead of moved

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I'm using qWidget which inherits QGLWidget and below the widget I have 2 buttons.
button1: +
button2: -

this is my code:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,_w,0,_h,-1,1);
    glViewport(_camera_pos_x,0,_w,_h);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(50,50);
        glVertex2i(200,200);
    glEnd();

   update();
}
```

I want each time I'm pressing the + button, the screen will move 10 pixels to the right which means the line should move to the left by 10 pixels.

This is the code when im pressing the button:

```
void right() {_camera_pos_x += 10;}
```

`_camera_pos_X` is just a member int which is initialized to 0.

When I'm pressing the button another line is rendered 10 pixels to the right and I see 2 lines

What's wrong with my code?

By the way, I think im using old code of OpenGL, is there a better way to render a line?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please take the next time a few minutes to correct at least the most obvious typos before submitting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note, that drawing with `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since more than 10 years.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

[`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml) specifies the transformation from normalized device coordinates to window coordinates. If you want to change the position of the line, then you have to draw the line at a different position, but that doesn't change the size of the viewport. Keep your viewport as large as the window:

```
glViewport(0, 0, _w, _h);
```

The default frame buffer is never cleared, so the rendering is always drawn on the rendering of the previous frames. Because of that, you can *"see 2 lines"*. Use [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) to clear the framebuffer at the begine of the rendering:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Change the model view matrix to set the positon of the line:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,_w,0,_h,-1,1);
glViewport(0, 0, _w, _h);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(_camera_pos_x, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(50,50);
    glVertex2i(200,200);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the old contents of the framebuffer, before drawing the new image. Put a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` at the beginning of `paintGL()`.